# I have tried many solutions to integrate ASP.NET Core 6 MVC with Vue.js but solutions do not work, I install webpack, but webpack.config.js not exsit

Tags: vue.js, webpack, asp.net-core-mvc

This is my `package.json` file all the dependencies I used already install.

This is my `index.js` file that I called vue component.

This is my `index.cshtml` file that I will called the component of vue as tag

`package.json`

```
{
    "name": "whoami",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
        "npm-watch": "^0.11.0",
        "webpack": "^5.64.4"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
        "vue": "^2.6.14",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.8",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
    }
}
```

`index.js`:

```
import vue from "vue";
import HomeComponnent from "./Home/home.veu";
vue.component("app", require("./Home/home.vue").default);
new veu({
    el: "#app",
    HomeComponnent,
});
```

`index.cshtml`:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div id="app">
     <home-compponnet></home-compponnet>

</div>

@section script {
     <script sre="@Url.Content("~")"></script>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not a direct answer, but save yourself a lot of headache and use [Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/)